# PowerShell custom module manifest does not expose functions declared

Tags: powershell

I've created a PowerShell module. The module exposes 3 functions. When I install it without a manifest directly the output will be:

```
> Import-Module AzureDD
> Get-Module | Where { $_.Name -eq 'AzureDD' }

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     0.0        AzureDD                             {New-AzureDDAppPermission, New-AzureDDAppRegistration, Sync-AzureDDStorageContainer}
```

This works because my last line in the psm file is:

```
Export-ModuleMember -Function New-AzureDDAppRegistration, New-AzureDDAppPermission, Sync-AzureDDStorageContainer
```

Now I wanted to add versionning and more meta data and went on with

```
> New-ModuleManifest -Path .\AzureDD.psd1 -ModuleVersion "2.0"
```

which creates a new file `AzuerDD.psd1`. In here I edited a lot of stuff. Besides other changes I also defined the exported functions as follows:

```
FunctionsToExport = @('New-AzureDDAppPermission', 'New-AzureDDAppRegistration', 'Sync-AzStorageContainer')
```

I can test this successfully:

```
> Test-ModuleManifest .\AzureDD.psd1

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0        AzureDD                             {New-AzureDDAppPermission, New-AzureDDAppRegistration, Sync-AzStorageContainer}
```

But when I actually import this it will not show any exported command:

```
> Import-Module .\AzureDD.psd1
> Get-Module | Where { $_.Name -eq 'AzureDD' }

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   2.0        AzureDD
```

See how it changed to `Manifest` compared to my very first snippet! I've ensured that I did `Remove-Module AzureDD -Force` all the time before I re-imported it.

Comment: Did you specify the existing `psm1` as the `RootModule` in the manifest? `FunctionsToExport` is like a sieve - it just _allows_ nested modules to export their functions, but they still have to be defined _somewhere_

Comment: Damn! You nailed it. I did specify it but I oversaw that it is commented out by default :-(. Please answer my question so that I can confirm it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FunctionsToExport` is like a sieve - it just *allows* nested modules to export their functions via the manifest, but they still have to be *defined* somewhere.

Make sure the script module (the `.psm1` file) is specified as the `RootModule` (or at least a `NestedModule`) in the manifest:

```
@{
  # Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
  RootModule = 'AzureDD.psm1'

  # ...
}
```